# How to create new object as default arg object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-2018

So we may have this in a reducer:

```
const defaultState = {...};

export const userReducer = (state = defaultState, action: any) => {
   // ...
}
```

is there some way to get a defaultState object for each call to userReducer?
Something like this:

```
const getDefaultState = () => ({...});

export const userReducer = (state = getDefaultState(), action: any) => {
   // ...
}
```

is this possible in JS? It might not be useful for a Redux reducer, but in general am curious.

Comment: What does not work in your second example? Isn't [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8971pwnc/2/) doing what you want?

Comment: I guess it is, I just didn't expect it to work, but it makes sense that it does, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as @blex, pointed out, your intentions are completely doable.

Your snippet has a minor typo that may be causing you issues: parameters with default values (i.e. `state`) must be ordered after parameters with non-default values (i.e. `action`).

Here's a minimalist example:

```js
let x = () => 3;
let y = (a, b = x()) => a + b;

console.log(y(5)); // 8
console.log(y(5, 1)); // 6
```

Comment: in order to accept the answer probably want one in a similar form to the OP?

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader, as it doesn't seem useful for posterity nor adds much of value to the answer. Less is often clearer.

Comment: less is more my jigga